# WPF UserControl Hosted in Popup Window not taking focus

Tags: wpf, popup, notifyicon

I'm using Philipp Sumi's [Notify Icon Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon), but I'm having a small issue with it, I'm displaying a custom Balloon method call

```
_TaskBarIcon.ShowCustomBalloon(_UserControlNotification, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PopupAnimation.Slide, null);
```

and this works great, until the main window of my application is minimized, the popup is still visible which is what I want to happen, but you cannot click into the popup. I have a listbox embedded with a list of the notifications I need to display to the user which is bound to a Observable collection on my viewmodel for the _userControlNotification. The idea is the user can go to lunch and will then see a list of the notifications when they come back at which point clicking on one of the notifications will fire off a command which navigates the application to the relevant information in the main window.

As I say the issue is with the popup not being clickable and taking focus. I know the popup will take mouse event as the mouse over event fires and also I have a image acting as a close icon on the usercontrol and the mouse down command fires perfectly fine still.

Any thoughts or direction on why the listbox itself will not take the click event and take focus i.e. select the appropiate item in the list.

Any ideas suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm at a bit of a standstill with this at the moment.

Emlyn